# Is it possible to compile assembly code in MSVC++?

Tags: visual-c++, assembly

Is it possible to create, edit, link, compile (is compile the word?) etc. assembly code in MSVC++?

Also, if it's not possible, how can I create an .exe out of plain text, ie: convert the text into whatever format is required to use assembly code, then turn the assembly code into an .exe. (I'd say compile, but I don't think that is the correct word here).

And finally, what are some good places to begin learning assembly code? Written in a way that someone who has little experience can use.

I know some of these questions are probably very stupid, but I have absolutely no experience in assembly code and am not exactly sure where to start.

Comment: "assemble" is the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On x86, yes.  You can use the [__asm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45yd4tzz(VS.80,printer).aspx) keyword to put assembly inline in your standard source files, and use the normal MS compile/link tools to compile everything together.

On x64 (or x86), you may need to use the [ML and ML64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0ksfwcf(VS.80,printer).aspx) command line compilers for assembly.

Comment: This only works on x86, and will cause you pain switching to x64.  The x64 compiler doesn't support inline assembly.

Comment: True: On x64, you need to use ml.exe.

Comment: @Michael: Updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: Anyone know *why* it isn't supported on x64?

Comment: FYI: ML is in \VC\bin, e.g. D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\ml.exe. This directory may not be in the path if vsvars32.bat has not been run.

Comment: @Justicle - I think it's because there is a range of x64 chips and MS still has to pretend to support Itanium !  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26td21ds.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio provides the [__asm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45yd4tzz(VS.71).aspx) keyword for compiling inline assembly in c and c++. There is also a good discussion here on the use of [inline assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93(VS.71).aspx). However if you are just talking about compiling assembly on it's own I'm not sure if Visual C++ is the correct tool however I'm pretty sure visual studio ships with the [MASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afzk3475(VS.71).aspx) assembler.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MASM), MASM has been shipped with all versions of Visual C later than VC6, and is also available in the Windows Driver Developer Kit. Versions supporting 16-bit real and protected modes, 32-bit, and 64-bit are all supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [__asm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45yd4tzz(VS.80).aspx) keyword to write inline assembly.

[pcasm-book(pdf)](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall08/cos318/precepts/pcasm-book.pdf) is a good tutorial to start assembly code programming.

Comment: I don't know if it makes any difference, but a later version of the pcasm-book can be found at http://drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/pcasm-book-pdf.zip. 2005-03-20 vs. 2006-07-23.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sort of.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\vc\bin>ml
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: ML [ options ] filelist [ /link linkoptions]
Run "ML /help" or "ML /?" for more info
```

You'd use the macro assembler. I don't know if Visual Studio will automatically "do the right thing" with .asm files, though, but you can certainly edit them with it and assemble them with ml.exe.

A good place to start learning assembly language might actually be by learning about reverse engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Look for information on the C++ 'asm' keyword.  It may be compiler specific, but I know VC++ supports it.